# How to click on element including href attribute using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

```html
<a ng-click="pageNavCtrl.executeCallback(item.callback, item.callbackArgs, $event)" ng-href="https://commerce.spscommerce.com/fulfillment/transactions/list/" translate-attr-title="fulfillment.pageNavLink.transactions" translate="fulfillment.pageNavLink.transactions" translate-default="Transactions" href="https://commerce.spscommerce.com/fulfillment/transactions/list/" title="Transactions"><span>Transactions</span></a>
```

I am using python and selenium to automate a web report.  I tried different find_element_by options but none worked.

In this scenario, I am trying move from Dashboard to Transactions.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63N9B.png)

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"https://commerce.spscommerce.com/fulfillment/transactions/list/")]')
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried xpath but received 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element' error.  I tried adding driver.implicitly_wait, but not working.